# Update HTML.Partial after Post only ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I like only to update the @Html.Partial("_CommentSection") after Button type="submit" id="PostButton" is clicked by the user.

At the moment I reload the whole page to see the new comment. But I think its not nice to have it.

Is there a way to do it maybe and you can help me a bit more to come to my goal.
Maybe with jquery - but I didn`t use this before and don't  know how to do

I have in asp.net project a partial view of this code:

```
@model MyProject.Models.Home

@foreach (var comment in MyProject.Controllers.HomeController.GetAllComments(Model.Id))
{
    <br />
    <div>
        <div>
            <a>
                @MyProject.Controllers.HomeController.GetUserName(comment.UserId)
            </a>
            added a comment -
            <span>
                <time>@comment.CommentCreated.ToString()</time>
            </span>
            <span id="edit-delete-comment">
                @using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteComment", "Home"))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                    if (MyProject.Controllers.HomeController.CheckIfUserIsCreator(User.Identity.Name, comment.CommentId))
                    {
                        if (!MyProject.Controllers.HomeController.CheckDateOfComment(comment.CommentId))
                        {
                            <div class="form-actions no-color">
                                @Html.Hidden("returnUrl", this.Request.RawUrl)
                                @Html.Hidden("CommentId", comment.CommentId)
                                <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="t" />
                            </div>
                        }
                    }

                }
            </span>

        </div>
        <br />
        <div>
            <p>
                @comment.CommentText
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr />
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateComment", "Home", FormMethod.Post, null))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="mt-5 d-flex flex-row">
        @Html.Hidden("returnUrl", this.Request.RawUrl)
        @Html.Hidden("HomeId", Model.Id)
        <textarea class="form-control" name="CommentText"></textarea>

        <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-block mt-2 post-btn" type="submit" id="PostButton">Post</button>

    </div>


}
```

My View:

```
<div id="partial-update">
    @Html.Partial("_CommentSection")
</div>
```

My Controller (update page after post is commented out)

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowOnlyOneRequest]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public void CreateComment([Bind(Include = "CommentId,CommentText,CommentCreated,UserId,HomeId")] Comment comment, string returnUrl, int HomeId)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        comment.CommentCreated = DateTime.Now;
        comment.UserId = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(i => i.UserEmail == User.Identity.Name).UserId;
        comment.HomeId = HomeId;

        db.Comments.Add(comment);
        db.SaveChanges();
        //return Redirect(returnUrl);
    }

    //return Redirect(returnUrl);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery and ajax call to get your partial view and update the only comment view on the screen instead of submitting and loading a whole form. I'm just giving you an idea. You need to work on this idea and expand it. Let me know if you need any help.

```
    $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    URL: "/Home/CreateComment",
                    dataType: 'html',
                    data:JSON.stringify({
                       comment : $("name=['CommentText']").val(),
                       HomeId : $("name=['HomeId']").val()
                    }}
                    success: function (result) {
    
                        $('#Your Div where you want to append your partial comment').html(result);
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        //Handle error here
                    }
                });

Create a model on the ASP.NET side :

    public Comment{
         public string Comment {get; set;}
         public string HomeId {get;set;
    }
Use this in a controller.

    CreateComment([HttpBody]Comment comment){
    comment.CommentCreated = DateTime.Now;
            comment.UserId = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(i => i.UserEmail == User.Identity.Name).UserId;
            comment.HomeId = comment.HomeId;
    
            db.Comments.Add(comment);
            db.SaveChanges();
    return PartialView("_CommentSection",comment)
    }
```

**Check this new code**

```
    @model MyProject.Models.Home

    <div class="comments">
        @foreach (var comment in MyProject.Controllers.HomeController.GetAllComments(Model.Id))
        {
            <br />
            <div>
                <div>
                    <a>
                        @MyProject.Controllers.HomeController.GetUserName(comment.UserId)
                    </a>
                    added a comment -
                    <span>
                        <time>@comment.CommentCreated.ToString()</time>
                    </span>
                    <span id="edit-delete-comment">
                        @using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteComment", "Home"))
                        {
                            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                            if (MyProject.Controllers.HomeController.CheckIfUserIsCreator(User.Identity.Name, comment.CommentId))
                            {
                                if (!MyProject.Controllers.HomeController.CheckDateOfComment(comment.CommentId))
                                {
                                    <div class="form-actions no-color">
                                        @Html.Hidden("returnUrl", this.Request.RawUrl)
                                        @Html.Hidden("CommentId", comment.CommentId)
                                        <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="t" />
                                    </div>
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    </span>

                </div>
                <br />
                <div>
                    <p>
                        @comment.CommentText
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr />
        }
    </div>



<div class="mt-5 d-flex flex-row">
    @Html.Hidden("returnUrl", this.Request.RawUrl)
    @Html.Hidden("HomeId", Model.Id)
    <textarea class="form-control" name="CommentText"></textarea>

    <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-block mt-2 post-btn" type="button" id="PostButton">Post</button>

</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#PostButton').click(function () {
            let comment = $('[name="CommentText"]').val();
            let homeId = $('[name="HomeId"]').val();
            let obj = {
                Comment: comment,
                HomeId : homeId
                }
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                URL: "/Home/CreateComment",
                dataType: 'html',
                data:JSON.stringify({
                   obj
                }),
                success: function (result) {
                    $('.comments').append(result);
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    //Handle error here
                }
            });
        })
        
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks looks cool. But never worked with ajax before. Where I need to put the ajax code and which div must be insert there

Comment: Ajax code will be in view after your razor code. it's a javascript code so you need to give <script></script> tag and write ajax code in document ready function. When you click on add comment button you will call a controller method using ajax call and that controller method will return a partial view. so if everything is successfully fetched you will get HTTP  200 OK response and response will be available in success method of ajax call that response you need to attach to a div where you want to show a comment.

Comment: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/ajax/form-post you can refer to this page.

Comment: Now I got it thanks. But still have one problem. If I submit the post the `ActionResult CreateComment` returns the `return PartialView("_CommentSection", home);`. After posting I really get just this partial as a view.. I will redirect from `Home/Details/1` to `Home/CreateComment`

Comment: I think the problem comes because of Html.BeginForm `using (Html.BeginForm("CreateComment", "Home",...`. But to be honest I dont know with what I need to replace the `Html.BeginForm`

Comment: I have edited my previous answer. Please check this new code. You will not use using and submit form that way. You will submit form using ajax function.